# Conditional Expectation of one dimensional Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Consider the one dimensional Brownian motion $B=(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$.

How to prove that for conditional expectation holds $\mathbb{E}[B_t \vert B_1]= tB_1$ where $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Is it $t<1$ or $t>1$?

Comment: $t \in [0,1]$ . Thank you for remark

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761479/finding-the-expected-value-of-martingale-increments-on-conditioned-on-brownian-b/2761583#2761583) could be helpful for you.

Comment: Just prove that $(B_t-tB_1)_{t \in [0,1]}$ is independent of $B_1$, by computing cov$(B_t-tB_1,B_1)$. Then the claim follows trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Set $W_t = \sqrt{t} X$ and $W_1-W_t = \sqrt{1-t} Y$. Then $X,Y$ are standard and independent Gaussian random variables.

You are asked to compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[W_t |W_1] = \mathbb{E}[W_t |W_t + (W_1-W_t)] = \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{t} X |\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y] 
$$

To make things simpler, assume that we condition on $\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y = z$ for some $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Define 
$$
a = \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{t} X |\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y = z]
$$
$$
b = \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{1-t} Y |\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y = z]
$$

Obviously $a+b = z$.

Besides it is easy to find a value $\alpha$ such that $\sqrt{t}X + \alpha \sqrt{1-t}Y$ is uncorrelated from $\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y$, and hence independent because $X,Y$ are independent Gaussians (so is any linear combination of those).

A quick computation yields $$\alpha = -\frac{t}{1-t}$$

This yields that 
$$
a + \alpha b = \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{t} X + \alpha \sqrt{1-t} Y |\sqrt{t} X + \sqrt{1-t} Y = z] = \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{t} X + \alpha \sqrt{1-t} Y] = 0
$$

Now, it is just a matter of solving for the system
$$
a+b=z, \quad a + \alpha b = 0
$$

which gives 
$$
a = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} z = t z
$$

Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}[W_t |W_1 = z] = t z, \quad \mathbb{E}[W_t |W_1] = t W_1
$$