# Why is conditional expectation of brownian motion with a negative sign?

Tags: brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, martingales, local-martingales

I have been reading up on the below thread:  [conditional expected value of a brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246528/conditional-expected-value-of-a-brownian-motion)

but I cannot understand how
$$\mathbb E\left[B_s - \frac{s}{t} B_t + \frac{s}{t} B_t\ \mid B_t\right] = \mathbb E\left[B_s - \frac{s}{t} B_t \mid B_t\right] - \mathbb E\left[\frac{s}{t} B_t \mid B_t\right].$$

Is it not supposed to be $\mathbb E\left[B_s - \frac{s}{t} B_t + \frac{s}{t} B_t\ \mid B_t\right]=\mathbb E\left[B_s - \frac{s}{t} B_t \mid B_t\right]+\mathbb E\left[\frac{s}{t} B_t\ \mid B_t\right]$?
i.e. a $+$ sign and not $-$ for the last when breaking it out separately.

Happy for all the help I can get!

Comment: Yes it should have been $+$ which is why the answer is $+\frac st B_t$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).